# Is cout.put() recommended over cout<< for printing characters

Tags: c++

**Background**

IIRC, from *Release 2.0* C++ stores single-character constants as type `char` and NOT `int`. But before *Release 2.0* a statement like

```
cout<<'A'
```

was problematic as it displays the ASCII value of 'A' ie 65 whereas:

```
char ch='A';
cout<<ch;
```

would display the right value ie 'A'.

Since the problem has been rectified in *Release 2.0*. I believe `cout.put()` lost the advantage it had over `cout<<`.

---

**Question**

Is there any other reason for recommending `cout.put()` over `cout<<` for printing characters?

Comment: There is no "C++ 2.0". Also `'A'` always was a `char`, I don't know what kind of compiler you're using but if you're having trouble with something like this it must be ancient and completely outdated...

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl: Yes there is. It's about 27 years old now.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley that's pre-standard. so we're talking about a specific implementation that's completely outdated? The same way some people call "Turbo C++ 3.1" just "C++ 3.1"?

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl: Well, no. Not really. It was the official C++ specification, as defined by the language's inventor. Outdated, certainly.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl : C++ 2.0 was released in 1989 and yes I'm talking about pre-standardized C++ here. Also, `'A' always was a char` may be right/not sure , it is just that cout couldn't differentiate it

Comment: C++ Release 1.0 happened more than thirty years ago. It is fossil, a museum piece. If you meet a specimen in the wild, please contact us immediately, we would like to study the lifecycle of the organization that is still using it. If you target Release 1.0 or 2.0, you are not likely to find answers to your questions here. Most users on this site were probably not born yet when it went totally obsolete.

Comment: @n.m. : This is not certainly production code ;) in fact digging history

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few differences between `cout<<` and `cout.put`, or should we say the overloaded `<<` operator and the `put` method from `std::basic_ostream` because this is not really limited to the global instance: `cout`.

The `<<` operator writes formatted output, the `put` method does not.

The `<<` operator sets the failbit if the output fails, the `put` method does not.

Personally I would go with the `<<` operator in almost all cases, unless I had specific needs to bypass the formatted output or not setting the failbit on error.

Using them can result in the following differences of output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Character: '" << setw(10) << 'A' << setw(0) << "'" << endl;
    cout << "Character: '" << setw(10);
    cout.put('A');
    cout << setw(0) << "'" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Character: '         A'
Character: 'A'
```

See the above in action: http://ideone.com/9N0VYn

Since the `put` method is unformatted it does not respect the manipulator set, there might be situations where that is indeed what you intend. But since it sounds like you only want to print out the character, I would prefer the `<<` operator, which respects the formatting.

And then there is the case of the `failbit` which is not being set, and that might even be more crucial.

Comment: Nice : I was not particularly concentrating on formatting aspect here though. Thanks for that bit on failbit